# Объединить javascript

Tags: javascript

Нашел три подключенных скрипта в заголовке и в подвале, каждый из которых делает http-запрос. Я решил их объединить в один файл. В результате 2-й и 3-й скрипты отказываются работать.

**Вопрос:**
Подскажите как объединить три javascript в одном файле, что бы уменьшить http-запросы?

**Файлы javascript**

1 скрипт Меню сайта

```
function( $ ) { // меню
    var body    = $( 'body' ),
        _window = $( window );
function() {
        var nav = $( '#primary-navigation, #secondary-navigation' ), button, menu;
        if ( ! nav ) {
            return;
        }
        button = nav.find( 'h1.menu-toggle, h2.menu-toggle' );
        if ( ! button ) {
            return;
        }
        menu = nav.find( '.nav-menu' );
        if ( ! menu || ! menu.children().length ) {
            button.hide();
            return;
        }
        $( 'h1.menu-toggle' ).on( 'click.pixelcom', function() {
            nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
        } );

        $( 'h2.menu-toggle' ).on( 'click.pixelcom', function() {
            nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-oncat' );
        } );        
    }
 }
```

2 скрипт - Показать скрыть блок div

```
function look(type){ // скрыть показать
        param=document.getElementById(type);
        if(param.style.display == "none") param.style.display = "block";
        else param.style.display = "none"
    }
```

3-й скрипт Вверх к заголовку страницы

```
function dd_scrolltotop(duration){// вверх
    duration = duration || 500
    var rootel = (document.compatMode =="BackCompat")? document.body : document.documentElement
    if (rootel.scrollTop == 0)
        rootel = document.body
    var curscrolltop = rootel.scrollTop, scrolltimer, elapsedtime, starttime = new Date().getTime(), animatedegree = 0
    var totaldis = curscrolltop
    clearTimeout(scrolltimer)
    function jumptop(){
        elapsedtime = new Date().getTime() - starttime
        if (elapsedtime < duration){
            rootel.scrollTop = totaldis - (totaldis * (1-Math.cos((elapsedtime/duration)*Math.PI)) / 2)
            scrolltimer = setTimeout(function(){jumptop()}, 10)
        }
    }
        jumptop()
    }
```

Comment: Консоль открывали? Какие ошибки выводит?

Comment: Да вроде на этот символ } ругается

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видимо, Вы при копировании теряете } или наоборот, лишнюю приписываете. В приведенных трех кусках количество открывающих и закрывающих фигурных скобок совпадает.
Я бы порекомендовал проставить ; в последнем скрипте, т.к. JS не всегда додумывается до этого, а если строки склеить - код становится просто текстом. И я бы переделал код уже на Jquery, раз уж подключаете его. Вышло бы гораздо короче :)

Comment: Отключил jQuery полностью, меню сделаю на чистом js. 
fremail СПС